# What is the subset of win32 Apis that are available?

Tags: windowsondevices

from: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/WelcomeAndFAQ.htm

Q: What APIs are supported in this release?
A: In this initial preview release, we’re supporting the standard Arduino Wiring API set, and a subset of Win32.

So what is the subset of win32 Apis that are available?

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: It is bound to be the subset that's supported by Windows Embedded Compact, combined with the restrictions imposed by Galileo.  You can't really get ahead until you get your hands on the dev kit, it is going to automatically restrict you to the winapi functions that can work.  If you don't already have it then it might be a while, looks like they got a lot of response.

Comment: The device is $49 from amazon, and the software is available from Ms for free. http://ms-iot.github.io/content/IBoughtAGalileo.htm